# windows Azure Paging Data

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, ios7

Hi I need to download over 2000 records from azure , the maximum you can download is 1000 at the  time , so I need to use a completion handler to download 200 at the time.

They posted this code as an example but I don't know how to use.

If I copy this to Xcode there is an error

- (bool)loadResults()  - Error " Expect Method Body "

Returning data in pages

Mobile Services limits the amount of records that are returned in a single response. To control the number of records displayed to your users you must implement a paging system. Paging is performed by using the following three properties of the MSQuery object:

BOOL includeTotalCount

NSInteger fetchLimit

NSInteger fetchOffset

In the following example, a simple function requests 20 records from the server and then appends them to the local collection of previously loaded records:

```
- (bool) loadResults() {
MSQuery *query = [self.table query];

query.includeTotalCount = YES;
query.fetchLimit = 20;
query.fetchOffset = self.loadedItems.count;
[query readWithCompletion:(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        //add the items to our local copy
        [self.loadedItems addObjectsFromArray:items];

        //set a flag to keep track if there are any additional records we need to load
        self.moreResults = (self.loadedItems.count < totalCount);
    }
}];
}
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting `Error " Expect Method Body "` then you copied it into your code incorrectly and there is a formatting issue.

If you want to load data with paging in a single call, I would do something like this:

in your .h file declare

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock) ();

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;
```

in your .m file

```
- (void)loadData
{
    self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"YOUR_URL" applicationKey:@"YOUR_KEY"]
    MSTable *table = [client tableWithName:@"YOUR_TABLE"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"YOUR_SELECT_FILTER"];
    MSQuery *query = [[MSQuery alloc] initWithTable:table predicate:predicate];
    //note the predicate is optional. If you want all rows skip the predicate
    [self loadDataRecursiveForQuery:query withCompletion:^{
        //do whatever you need to do once the data load is complete
    }];
}

- (void)loadDataRecursiveForQuery:(MSQuery *)query withCompletion:(CompletionBlock)completion
{
    query.includeTotalCount = YES;
    query.fetchLimit = 1000; //note: you can adjust this to whatever amount is optimum
    query.fetchOffset = self.results.count;
    [query readWithCompletion:(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            //add the items to our local copy
            [self.results addObjectsFromArray:items];

            if (totalCount > [results count]) {
                [self loadDataRecursiveForQuery:query withCompletion:completion];
            } else {
                completion();
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code, but it should work more or less.